# Add verb to the noun and create a new noun

Tags: verb, phrase, noun, infinitive, nominalization

Can we in German add the infinitive of a verb to the end of any noun and create new noun?

I searched in a dictionary for examples. Some of the words I checked do exist, but some of them do not. I want to know when it is possible, and when/whether an "s" is needed between the noun and the added infintive?
For example:

> Das Musik***hören***

> Das Schule***gehen***

> Das Kleidungs***kaufen***

Comment: the noun ingredient isn't important at all, see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible grammatically. Take into account that you need to use the correct prepositions, though:

- *Musik hören* → *das Musikhören*
- *zur Schule gehen* → *das Zurschulegehen*
- *Kleidung kaufen* → *das Kleidungkaufen*

Even though it is possible and grammatically valid, you would usually not use this construction. This is especially true in case of prepositions involved. It sounds rather complicated then and one would use a construction with an [explective *es*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletivum#Expletive_im_Deutschen) and a clause instead of a noun-phrase, I guess. The following sentence is possible but sounds unidiomatic:

> Das Zurschulegehen macht den Kindern Freude.

You would rather say:

> Es macht den Kindern Freude, zur Schule zu gehen.

As far as I can see, no [Fugen-s](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut#Bildung_zusammengesetzter_W%C3%B6rter) is used.

Answer (score 3):

Die durch [jonathan.scholbach](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/62230/5437) erläuterte Möglichkeit der Zusammenschreibung sollte man auf Konstruktionen aus wenigen Wörtern beschränken.

### Durchkopplung

In Fällen, wo die Kombination unübersichtlich zu werden droht, wo also die Gliederung schwer zu erkennen ist, kann man die sogenannte
[Durchkopplung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durchkopplung) einsetzen, die die Zwischenräume der Ausgangskonstruktion in Form von Bindestrichen überführt.

Beispiele:

> Das *Zur-Schule-Gehen* hat an Reiz verloren.

> Diese Komplexität ist zum *Aus-der-Haut-Fahren*!

Die Regel für Substantivierungen von Infinitiv-Phrasen ist:
Anfangs groß, das substantivierte Verb am Ende ebenfalls groß, der Rest bleibt unangetastet, wird aber per Bindestrich durchgekoppelt.

Dieses Muster wurde durch die jüngsten Rechtschreibreformen nicht angetastet.

### Addendum: Substantive Verb Extensions

The noun ingredient you asked about is *not necessary* for making a new noun from a verb. The crucial ingredient is the substantivized verb. The topping may vary, see these examples:

> das *Schönschreiben* (adverb+verb)

> das *Gegenlesen* (proposisition+verb)